# SQL Finding data from similar tables

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have a 50 tables with similar structures with name `TABLE_1`, `TABLE_2`, `TABLE_3` etc. I want to select some information like `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CRM_ID = 100` but I dont know which table consists this ID. I guess that I should make a union with this tables and make a query from this union but I am afraid that it is not the best solution. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Can't you store all data in one single table?

Comment: You don't know which table contains a column `CRM_ID`, or is it that all tables have that column, you just don't know which one has a ROW with `CRM_ID = 100`? I read the question to mean the latter, but you already received an answer that assumes the former. Please advise.

Comment: No, all this tables contain CRM_ID, but I want to find a row with CRM_ID=100

Answer (score 0):

To find the table containing the field CRM_ID, you can use:

```
select TABLE_NAME
from SYS.ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'CRM_ID'
```

From here, you can query the relevant tables with your union

Comment: No, all this tables contain CRM_ID, but I want to find a row with CRM_ID=100

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'table_1', count(*) from table_1 where CMR_ID = 100
union all
select 'table_2', count(*) from table_2 where CMR_ID = 100
[.....]
```

If you have 50 tables, you may want to use some advanced text editing so you don't have to type the same line 50 times.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything different from a `UNION` to get what you need.
However, I would like to avoid repeating all the code every time you need to query your tables, for example by creating a view:

```
create view all_my_tables as
  select * from table1
  union
  select * from table2
  ...
```

and then

```
select *
from all_my_tables
where crm_id = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I would

```
create a view table_all as 
select * from table_1 union all
select * from table_2 ...
```

but I guess you have 50 tables due to some performance reason like creating partitioning without partitioned table. If that is the case you need some table that simulates index and you need to have data "sorted". Then create table that contains: table_name, min_val, max_val:
table_1, 1, 1000
table_2, 1001, 2000

and procedure selecting looks like:

```
procedure sel(crmid) is
a varchar2(10);
value table%rowtype;
begin
select table_name into a from lookup where crmid between min_val and max_val;
execute immediate 'select * from ' || a || ' where crm_id = ' || crmid into value;
--do logic with value
end;
```

but if data is not ordered you need to iterate selects in loop. In such case use view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select tmp.tablename from (
select 'table1' as tablename from table1 where CRM_ID=100 
union all
select 'table2' as tablename from table2 where CRM_ID=100
) as tmp
```

Comment: My fault. Did not read the part with "Oracle". This solution is for MySQL.